# improve my array to display the_title, category, excerpt for homepage

Tags: homepage

Im trying to create an array for my bespoke homepage template which gets the title, category, featured thumbnail and excerpt from the last 3 blog posts and puts them into the correct divs for styling.

So far i have managed to come up with the following:

```
<div id="content2Wrapper">

 <?php
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 3, 'order'=> 'DSC', 'orderby' => 'date' );
$postslist = get_posts( $args );
foreach ($postslist as $post) :  setup_postdata($post); ?> 

<div>
    <div id="widget2left">
        <h3><?php echo substr(get_the_title(),0,58); ?></h3><p>
        <h5><?php echo substr(the_category(),0,70); ?></h5>
        <p><?php echo substr(get_the_excerpt(),0,165); ?><p> 
        <br> <p><?php the_post_thumbnail(220,120,true); ?> </p>
    </div><!--end widget 2 left-->

</div>
```

```
</div><!--end wrapper-->
```

But as you can see this displays 3 posts order by date, but the substr code is cutting the ends of words off & also the images are not displaying at the 220*120 resolution.

here is an image of what i am trying to acheive http://s16.postimg.org/eqqsent91/screen2.png

My code knowledge is rusty so any help to improve this code would be really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

```
 <div id="content2Wrapper">

 <?php
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 3, 'order'=> 'DSC', 'orderby' => 'date' );
$postslist = get_posts( $args );
while(have_posts()) :  the_post(); ?> 

<div>
    <div id="widget2left">
        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3><p>
        <h5><?php the_category(','); ?></h5>
        <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?><p> 
        <br><p><?php the_post_thumbnail(array(220,120)); ?> </p>
    </div><!--end widget 2 left-->

</div><?php endwhile; ?>
```

I suggest you to not to use `substr` with title and category function
and to trim post excerpt you can set limit in you *functions.php* file ( [example](http://bavotasan.com/2009/limiting-the-number-of-words-in-your-excerpt-or-content-in-wordpress/) )
and for displaying image in proper size you can also use [`add_image_size`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size) function to define a new image size in your *functions.php* file